# Is it a good idea to intentionally discharge lithium batteries to 80%

Tags: battery

Manufacturers recommend keeping lithium batteries between 40 and 80 percent charged. I tried, but sometimes I let my phone get higher than that. Then I try to bring it down  soon as possible, either by playing graphic intensive apps or by charging some other device off my phone via USB-c. Is there a point in bringing it down once it already has overcharged. Which method is better/worse?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no. You want to minimize the throughput in any event. You can't extend the life of a battery by using it. It's not going to come to any harm just sitting there.

Comment: @PhilSweet actually, my understanding of the mechanism by which LiPos degrade at high charge is that it is a chemical reaction that happens over a span of hours.  However, I have this information verbally from someone who is a scary-astute model airplane hobbyist, not a battery chemistry professional.  Typical usage in such circles is to charge your batteries of an evening, go flying the next day, and bring all your batteries to a state of half charge (by charging or discharging) before you put them back into storage.

Answer (score 1):

It is customary for reputed mobile phone manufactures to design electronics battery charging circuits to ensure that batteries are changed between 40% and 80%. This will address your concerns. By discharging the phone your reducing the battery capacity to less and 80%.

To extend battery life, avoid over heating your phone. High temperatures can also cause battery to degrade faster.